Is this what a coordinate system transformation means?
What does it mean for points in some coordinate space A to be transformed into coordinates of some space B?
Is it that those points in A are transformed via a matrix that represents the basis of coordinate space B, by multiplying the points by that matrix, and then for there to be an additional translation of those points, such that this translation represents the coordinates of B's origin, in the coordinate system of A, being made coincident with the origin of A?

There is no universal or standard interpretation of the phrase "points in coordinate space $A$ are transformed into coordinates of $B$". In order for us to give you a meaningful answer, you'll have to tell us about the context in which you encountered this phrase.

The context is 3d graphics. Like, transforming vertices in world space to be in camera space. But, I was hoping to find an universal interpretation for the phrase.

The kind of transformation you seem to be discussing is an affine transformation, which is indeed commonly discussed in the context of 3D graphics. Your description does seem to be accurate. Can you clarify what you mean when you say that you're looking for a "universal" interpretation?

...Are you looking for an interpretation that works for all discussions of graphics? An interpretation that works for all discussions involving matrices? An interpretation that works for all discussions involving the words "transform" and "points" in some capacity?

Well, the more universal the better. But, if that is not possible, then I would be content with a definition that's universal enough for 3d graphics.

I think the only way that we can stick to the level of detail in the explanation you offered is to stick to the discussion of affine transformations. Note that people will sometimes use "transformation" to refer to linear transformations, which are specifically the affine transformations that have no associated translation (so the origin must be mapped to the origin). When we veer into other interpretations of the word "transformation", we move away from matrices and even away from "points" or "coordinates" as you think of them, which seems unhelpful for your context

That's fair enough.

It would be helpful if we could pin down what exactly you feel is missing from your current understanding of affine transformations. If I had to take a guess, the issue with what you presented is that although you understand the step-by-step process of computing the end result, you lack an "intuitive" or "big picture" understanding. Perhaps you're after a geometric interpretation of what's happening to those points. Is that accurate?

If you're familiar with linear transformations in some capacity, then perhaps it is helpful to frame things like this: affine transformations are linear transformations without the requirement that they treat the origin as a "special" or "central" point. For example, the only "linear" rotations are rotations whose axis goes through the origin, but every rotation, regardless of whether its axis passes through the origin, is an affine transformation.

The key insight for me is knowing whether "transforming objects from space A to space B" requires that the origin of B is made coincident with the origin of A. Because if there is no such requirement, then to me it seems like its just transforming in space A by some amount. Also, it so happens that the definition of a world-space to camera-space transform, in the context of 3d graphics, makes the origin of the camera-space coincident with the origin of the world-space.

In the context of affine transformations (i.e. if we allow for matrix multiplication and translation), then there is no requirement that origins be mapped to origins. If we look at 3-dimensional transformations purely in terms of coordinates, then indeed there is no difference between moving within a 3D system to moving from one 3D system to another; which one of these perspectives is a matter of how these coordinates are meant to be interpreted.

Also, for an instance of where origins are not mapped to origins, consider a transformation from one camera space to another. We can take the worldspace origin to be the position of one of the cameras for the sake of convenience (and do so as a matter of course if only the one camera is considered), but the origin of the second camera's camera-space would not correspond to the origin of either the first camera or our worldspace coordinates.

I can accept your comment about there being no requirements for origins to be mapped to origins. But, for your immediately preceding example, I don't think is correct. If we map objects that can be seen to the space of the first camera then,  in this case, there hasn't being a mapping to the second camera's space. However, if such second camera mapping does take place, then all the objects would be in the space of that second camera, and its origin would also coincide with the world origin. So, whenever a mapping to camera space happens, then that camera's origin coincides with the world.

Two different coordinate systems are just two different descriptions of the same point in space. The space itself is not transformed. Think about an airplane being tracked by two different nearby airports. The airplane will be at a different bearing from each airport so they will use a different set of coordinates to track the same plane.

@JohnDouma: That's a good comment and a good example. Thank you.
